# Angular Form Validation and Sending HTML Template with Form

Tags: angularjs

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xd2cxvVG1HoAie80XXA6?p=preview) is a Plunkr demonstrating my issue.

I apologize if it seems like this should be two separate questions, but it seems to me my issues are related.

I have a form that requires a name and email address, and when submitted, sends those, in addition to an HTML email template, to my back end. Here is an abbreviated version of my form:

```
<form novalidate id="send-email" data-ng-controller="SendListController" ng-submit="sendEmail()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Hidden input populated with compiled HTML from the controller -->
        <input type="hidden" id="htmlTemplate" name="htmlTemplate" ng-value="form.compiledHtml" data-ng-model="form.compiledHtml">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':form.name.$invalid && form.name.$dirty}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" data-ng-model="form.name" required>
        <span class="help-block has-error" ng-if="form.name.$dirty">this field is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="loading">
            <span ng-show="!loading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> mail it!
            </span>
            <span ng-show="loading">
                <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="loading" ></span> sending . . .
                </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The `loading` and `!loading` functionality is working, and my hidden inputs are populated properly, and my communication with the back end is fine. The error classes are being added to the elements, but the form errors are never shown and the form submits even when required inputs have the classes `ng-dirty` and `ng-invalid`.

Here is my controller (and, by the way, I REALLY don't like looking at all that HTML markup in the JS, so if anyone has better ideas, please let me know):

```
app.controller('SendListController', ['$scope', 'list', '$http', '$compile', '$timeout', 'toastr', function ($scope, list, $http, $compile, $timeout, toastr)
{
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.loading = false;

    var container = angular.element('<div></div>');

    // list is a service
    $scope.list = list;

    container.html(
        '<h1>{{list.listTitle}}</h1>' +
        '<ul>' +
            '<li data-ng-repeat="item in list.show()">' +
                '<span> {{item.DisplayName}} &mdash; </span>' +
                '<span> {{item.Description}} &mdash; </span>' +
                '<span> {{item.Count}} {{item.CountText}} &mdash; </span>' +
                '<span> ${{item.Price}} </span>' +
            '</li>' +
        '</ul>'
    );

    $compile(container)($scope);

    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.form.compiledHtml = container.html();
        // htmlToPlaintext() is a private method whose definition I have not
        // included here. Trust that it works.
        $scope.form.plainText = htmlToPlainText(container.html());
    });

    $scope.sendEmail = function()
    {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.post('/mail-it', $scope.form)

        .success(function (response)
        {
            if (response.successMessage)
            {
                toastr.success('Success', response.successMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                toastr.warning(response.errorMessage);
            }

            $scope.form = {};
            $scope.loading = false;
        })
        .error(function (response)
        {
            toastr.error('Error', 'Uh-oh! Something went wrong. Try again!');
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }
```

Again, everything is working (which, as we all know, doesn't mean it's good or right), EXCEPT the form validation. Is this somehow related to my injecting the compiled HTML, and in either case, is there a better way to send that template along with my form?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your problem is. Can you elaborate on 1) what specifically in your model is not updating, and 2) what is the expected behaviour of your form validation, and where you realize it isn't working? You say you're taking a name and email address but your code & your plunkr only has a 'full name' field

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The validation is not working. So the element `<span class="help-block has-error" ng-if="form.name.$dirty">`  is not shown when the field has the class `ng-dirty`, and the form submits even when those elements have the class `ng-invalid`. I noted that I didn't include the entire form, just enough to demonstrate my issue.

Comment: Your form has no name. Add `name="myForm"`, and use `ng-if="myForm.name.$invalid"`.

Comment: I've tried that, and it produces a situation where the `name` and `email` fields are both populated with `[object Object]` and submission throws an Angular error about converting circular structure to JSON . . .

Comment: That's because your ng-model is wrong. Don't use `myForm.something` in the ng-model. You're confusing the form and ngModel controllers, which are accessible through the name of the form and represent the state of the form components, and the model, which should be a different object, and represents the data displayed in the components.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shout when I'm back in front of my computer and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that wasn't quite the case, but it led me in the right direction. I define the `sendEmailForm` object in the controller and give it a property `loading: false`. I then have access to the form fields using `ng-model="sendEmailForm.fieldname"`. The form itself gets a different `name` attribute (let's say `name="form"`) and I have access to all the validation classes using the form name, like so: `ng-if="form.fieldName.$invalid"`. In other words, my problem was that I was using those classes as properties of the sendEmailForm object.